# Clean architecture and authentication

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2, clean-architecture

How should authentication be implemented to fit in the Clean Architecture pattern?

Say I need a token (oauth, googleapi, I see you) for some of my API requests. How should I get this token from my login screen and User Repository to my RandomDataRepository for example?

It seems strange to put that in each of my RandomData Use Cases, and strange too to have my remote RandomData layer talking to another Repository module.

Should the token be passed for every request (kinda ugly if my repository can switch from cache / remote), or should it be injected once and referenced somewhere, like in an interceptor?

I found [this](https://medium.com/@muhammadahmedabutalib/dagger2-with-repsitorypattern-room-and-retrofit-2ff918831250) but I don't understand the login worfklow and there's no full code)

Thanks !

Comment: I'd take this to the software engineering stack exchange.  Its not a great fit for SO.

Comment: We do this in the use case in my company. The use case uses multiple repositories and just combines data from them. Unfortunately, this leads to exactly what you said - having to always request the token in almost every use case. We haven't found a better way, that also enables us to easily test. Having the use case composed of several repositories made it straight forward.

Comment: On @GabeSechan recommendation I started digging in the SE stack and found this https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/366586/clean-architecture-google-facebook-login-and-data-layer